# How to improve this SQL Server query with multiple 'CASE'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have this SQL query for SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
Declare @fechaDesde DateTime
Declare @fechaHasta DateTime

set @fechaDesde = '01/01/2014 00:00:00.000'
set @fechaHasta = '31/12/2014 23:59:59.999'

Select Cuenta, isnull(sum(SaldoDebe), 0) as SumaDebe, 
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber), 0) as SumaHaber,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe01), 0) as SumaDebe01,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe02), 0) as SumaDebe02,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe03), 0) as SumaDebe03,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe04), 0) as SumaDebe04,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe05), 0) as SumaDebe05,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe06), 0) as SumaDebe06,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe07), 0) as SumaDebe07,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe08), 0) as SumaDebe08,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe09), 0) as SumaDebe09,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe10), 0) as SumaDebe10,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe11), 0) as SumaDebe11,
    isnull(sum(SaldoDebe12), 0) as SumaDebe12,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber01), 0) as SumaHaber01,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber02), 0) as SumaHaber02,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber03), 0) as SumaHaber03,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber04), 0) as SumaHaber04,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber05), 0) as SumaHaber05,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber06), 0) as SumaHaber06,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber07), 0) as SumaHaber07,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber08), 0) as SumaHaber08,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber09), 0) as SumaHaber09,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber10), 0) as SumaHaber10,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber11), 0) as SumaHaber11,
    isnull(sum(SaldoHaber12), 0) as SumaHaber12

From(
      Select c.Código as Cuenta,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber,

      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 1 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe01,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 2 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe02,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 3 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe03,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 4 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe04,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 5 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe05,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 6
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe06,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 7 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe07,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 8 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe08,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 9 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe09,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 10 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe10,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 11 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe11,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 12 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe12,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 1 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber01,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 2 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber02,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 3 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber03,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 4 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber04,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 5 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber05,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 6 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber06,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 7 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber07,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 8 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber08,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 9 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber09,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 10 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber10,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 11 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber11,
      case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 12 
           then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber12

    From Cuentas as c inner join Diario as d on c.Código = d.Cuenta
    Where d.Fecha >= @fechaDesde and d.Fecha <= @fechaHasta
    ) as table1
group by Cuenta
order by Cuenta
```

...

There is two tables: Cuentas and Diario. In table Diario I save movements of the accouns. And here are the tables:

### Cuentas

It has two fields and 300000 rows: Código and Nombre. It contains the accounts used in the table Diario

### Diario

Contains movements of money between accounts of 'Cuentas' table. His structure is

```
    [Apunte] [int] NOT NULL, --Identity
    [Fecha] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Concepto] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Cuenta] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
    [Importe] [float] NULL,
    [Debe_Haber] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Diario] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Apunte] ASC
)



      Cuenta    Concepto    Importe Debe_Haber  Fecha
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    572000006   C/Ef.A2003313E01/01-572000006   123,52  H 01/02/14
    433000077   C/Ef.A2003326E01/01-572000006   21,84   D 01/03/14
    572000006   C/Ef.A2003326E01/01-572000006   21,84   H 01/03/14
    430000754   C/Ef.A2003503E01/01-572000006   54,83   D 11/04/14
    572000006   C/Ef.A2003503E01/01-572000006   54,83   H 12/05/14
    430000807   C/Ef.F2030395E03/03-572000006   50,61   D 22/05/14
    572000006   C/Ef.F2030395E03/03-572000006   50,61   H 23/08/14
    430000497   C/Ef.F2034038E01/01-572000006   581,62  D 05/09/14
    572000006   C/Ef.F2034038E01/01-572000006   581,62  H 06/09/14
```

Fecha is a DateTime field.
I have included the index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<IX_Diario_Fecha>]
ON [dbo].[Diario] ([Fecha])
INCLUDE ([Cuenta],[Importe],[Debe_Haber])
```

My query takes 3/4 secs, I need improve it to get results faster.

Comment: 'Case' statements do not directly affect performance (at least when not used in 'where' or other similar clauses). How many records does your query process? Have you created indexes on Diario table Pista nad Fecha fields? Show us execution plan.

Comment: Table Diario has 300000 rows. I still have created this index, but there is not hardly time gain: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<IX_Diario_Pista_Fecha>]
ON [dbo].[Diario] ([Pista],[Fecha])
INCLUDE ([Cuenta],[Importe],[Debe_Haber])`

Comment: what's the distribution of records for Pista? Maybe remove the Pista from the index and add the condition d.Pista in ('00') as a where clause to your index. Not sure if it would help that much performance wise..

Comment: @mxix Forget the pista isn't important. I have removed it. I hace edited the post.

Comment: If you query over all 300'000 rows, then 3 seconds is not that bad. If your results come from say 10'000 rows, then I think some indexing may help. Looking at SQL server performance data, what resource will max - CPU or disk? If for example disk subsystem is slow, then you just can't make your query faster than data reading time.

Comment: @Arvo The query return 14000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this updated query,I removed the multiple `isnull` and added `else 0` in case to handle nulls.

```
DECLARE @fechaDesde DATETIME
DECLARE @fechaHasta DATETIME

SET @fechaDesde = '01/01/2014 00:00:00.000'
SET @fechaHasta = '31/12/2014 23:59:59.999'

Select Cuenta, sum(SaldoDebe)as SumaDebe, sum(SaldoHaber)as SumaHaber,
sum(SaldoDebe01)as SumaDebe01,
sum(SaldoDebe02)as SumaDebe02,
sum(SaldoDebe03)as SumaDebe03,
sum(SaldoDebe04)as SumaDebe04,
sum(SaldoDebe05)as SumaDebe05,
sum(SaldoDebe06)as SumaDebe06,
sum(SaldoDebe07)as SumaDebe07,
sum(SaldoDebe08)as SumaDebe08,
sum(SaldoDebe09)as SumaDebe09,
sum(SaldoDebe10)as SumaDebe10,
sum(SaldoDebe11)as SumaDebe11,
sum(SaldoDebe12)as SumaDebe12,

sum(SaldoHaber01)as SumaHaber01,
sum(SaldoHaber02)as SumaHaber02,
sum(SaldoHaber03)as SumaHaber03,
sum(SaldoHaber04)as SumaHaber04,
sum(SaldoHaber05)as SumaHaber05,
sum(SaldoHaber06)as SumaHaber06,
sum(SaldoHaber07)as SumaHaber07,
sum(SaldoHaber08)as SumaHaber08,
sum(SaldoHaber09)as SumaHaber09,
sum(SaldoHaber10)as SumaHaber10,
sum(SaldoHaber11)as SumaHaber11,
sum(SaldoHaber12)as SumaHaber12

From(
Select c.Código as Cuenta,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber,

case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 1 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe01,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 2 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe02,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 3 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe03,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 4 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe04,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 5 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe05,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 6 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe06,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 7 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe07,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 8 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe08,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 9 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe09,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 10 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe10,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 11 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe11,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'D' and Month(fecha) = 12 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoDebe12,

case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 1 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber01,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 2 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber02,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 3 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber03,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 4 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber04,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 5 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber05,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 6 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber06,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 7 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber07,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 8 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber08,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 9 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber09,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 10 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber10,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 11 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber11,
case When d.Debe_Haber = 'H' and Month(fecha) = 12 then d.Importe else 0 end as SaldoHaber12

From Cuentas as c 
inner join 
(select distinct [Fecha],
              [Cuenta],
              isnull([Importe],0) as [Importe],
              [Debe_Haber] from Diario) as d 
on c.Código = d.Cuenta
Where d.Fecha >= @fechaDesde and d.Fecha <= @fechaHasta
) as table1
group by Cuenta
order by Cuenta



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<IX_Diario_Fecha>]
ON [dbo].[Diario] ([Fecha])
INCLUDE ([Cuenta],[Importe],[Debe_Haber])
```

Comment: The index improved the query a little. But the query you show me doesn't work.

Comment: It´s not I´m looking for. Table 'Cuentas' contains account codes with their name and table 'Diario' contains movements of money between accounts. I need the import summatory from the accounts but distinguishing what is marked as 'H' or 'D' in the 'Debe_Haber' field.

Comment: Yes. i tried to do exactly that. by the way what do you mean bu 'doesn't work'? anyways i have corrected a syntax error.please try now and let me know

Comment: The query works but the result it´s not correct because the balance  account must be separated what is Debe_Haber = 'H' and Debe_Haber = 'D'. You gave me all together.

Comment: Great!. It works fine. An only mistake: the index it´s not correct because you add field 'Fecha' in the include clause.

Comment: Now the query only takes 1 second!. The bounty is for you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes! Accepted your edit.Please let me know what is the difference you are seeing with this working query.

Comment: Difference is 3 seconds less than initial query that i proposed.

Answer (score 1):

The driver of performance isn't the `case` statements.  It is the `join`, `where`, and `group by`.

```
    From Cuentas c inner join
         Diario d
         on c.Código = d.Cuenta
    Where d.Pista in ('00') and d.Fecha >= @fechaDesde and d.Fecha <= @fechaHasta
```

I would recommend the following indexes: `diario(Pista, Fecha, Cuenta)` and `Cuentas(Codigo)`.

You could also try reformulating the query using `pivot`.  That may be marginally faster -- and the same  indexes should work for that as well.

Comment: SQL Server recommended me the same. I still have created this index, but there is not hardly time gain. Thanks

Comment: How could I use PIVOT in this query?

Answer (score 1):

I agree (as usual)  with @Gordon regarding the case statements, they are almost certainly not the cause of your performance problems.

Pivot statements do what your extensive case statements do (quite literally, if you drill down far enough into the execution plans). They’d make you’re code a bit more legible [*this is debatable, as pivot syntax is pretty arcane*], but again shouldn’t affect performance all that much.

The likeliest source of your performance issue is going to be from the join between Diario and Cuentas.

**Cuentas**:  Is there a primary key or an index on column Código? This might be an issue as you are reading all rows from this table that have any rows selected from Diario. Clustered vs. non-clustered (index) may also be an issue, but possibly not so relevant for this query.

**Diario**: Is there any index on column Código, or a compound index where Código is the first column? I suspect this is the real problem. Picture SQL performing the join: it takes the first Cuenta, finds all Diarios for that Cuenta (filtering by date), then does it again for every other Cuenta. If there is no index on Código, then for every Cuenta it as to read *every single row* in Diario in order to be sure it’s found them all. And then it has to do it again for the next Cuenta, and the next, and the next… 300,000 * however many Cuentas you have. Ow. With an index on Código—and this really should be the clustered index on the table—the looping process can retrieve only those rows in Diarios that have the desired Código, saving massive time on looping, I/O, and so forth.

I generally don’t mess with `INCLUDE` statements unless I’m dead certain they’d help the overall system, and not just the query I’m working on right now. Might help, might not, get the join working first.

Comment: - In 'Cuentas' there is only a PK with the field 'Código'. This field is in Diario as field Cuenta (names are different). - In Diario there is a PK with autonumeric field 'Apunte' and then I have created <IX_Diario_Fecha> index.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following index: `Diario (Cuenta, Pista, Fecha) include (Debe_Haber, Importe)`. The order of key columns is important, but you may play with it - it is possible that some other order will do the trick if the aforementioned one would not.

On the other hand, I can say from my experience that the best place to pivot the data is the client application.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause for poor performance, I feel, is the constant call of the scalar valued functions for each record. To avoid it, you can store one dataset in a indexed temp table and remove redundant code. Try this:

```
select Month(fecha) FechaMon, *
into #FechaDiarioDebe
from Diario
where Debe_Haber = 'D'

select Month(fecha) FechaMon, *
into #FechaDiarioHaber
from Diario
where Debe_Haber = 'H'

create index IX_Fecha_Cuenta_Debe on #FechaDiarioDebe(fecha) include (FechaMon, Importe)
create index IX_Fecha_Cuenta_Debe on #FechaDiarioHaber(fecha) include (FechaMon, Importe)

Select  Cuenta, 
sum(SaldoDebe) as SumaDebe, 
sum(SaldoHaber) as SumaHaber,
sum(SaldoDebe01) as SumaDebe01,
sum(SaldoDebe02) as SumaDebe02,
sum(SaldoDebe03) as SumaDebe03,
sum(SaldoDebe04) as SumaDebe04,
sum(SaldoDebe05) as SumaDebe05,
sum(SaldoDebe06) as SumaDebe06,
sum(SaldoDebe07) as SumaDebe07,
sum(SaldoDebe08) as SumaDebe08,
sum(SaldoDebe09) as SumaDebe09,
sum(SaldoDebe10) as SumaDebe10,
sum(SaldoDebe11) as SumaDebe11,
sum(SaldoDebe12) as SumaDebe12,
sum(SaldoHaber01) as SumaHaber01,
sum(SaldoHaber02) as SumaHaber02,
sum(SaldoHaber03) as SumaHaber03,
sum(SaldoHaber04) as SumaHaber04,
sum(SaldoHaber05) as SumaHaber05,
sum(SaldoHaber06) as SumaHaber06,
sum(SaldoHaber07) as SumaHaber07,
sum(SaldoHaber08) as SumaHaber08,
sum(SaldoHaber09) as SumaHaber09,
sum(SaldoHaber10) as SumaHaber10,
sum(SaldoHaber11) as SumaHaber11,
sum(SaldoHaber12) as SumaHaber12  

from(

Select c.Código as Cuenta,
d.Importe  SaldoDebe,
NULL SaldoHaber,
case When FechaMon = 1 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe01,
case When FechaMon = 2 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe02,
case When FechaMon = 3 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe03,
case When FechaMon = 4 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe04,
case When FechaMon = 5 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe05,
case When FechaMon = 6 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe06,
case When FechaMon = 7 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe07,
case When FechaMon = 8 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe08,
case When FechaMon = 9 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe09,
case When FechaMon = 10 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe10,
case When FechaMon = 11 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe11,
case When FechaMon = 12 then d.Importe end as SaldoDebe12,
0 SaldoHaber01,
0 SaldoHaber02,
0 SaldoHaber03,
0 SaldoHaber04,
0 SaldoHaber05,
0 SaldoHaber06,
0 SaldoHaber07,
0 SaldoHaber08,
0 SaldoHaber09,
0 SaldoHaber10,
0 SaldoHaber11,
0 SaldoHaber12

From Cuentas as c inner join #FechaDiarioDebe as d on c.Código = d.Cuenta
Where d.Fecha >= @fechaDesde and d.Fecha <= @fechaHasta 

union all

Select c.Código as Cuenta,
NULL  SaldoDebe,
d.Importe SaldoHaber,
0 SaldoHaber01,
0 SaldoDebe02,
0 SaldoDebe03,
0 SaldoDebe04,
0 SaldoDebe05,
0 SaldoDebe06,
0 SaldoDebe07,
0 SaldoDebe08,
0 SaldoDebe09,
0 SaldoDebe10,
0 SaldoDebe11,
0 SaldoDebe12,
case When FechaMon = 1 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber01,
case When FechaMon = 2 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber02,
case When FechaMon = 3 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber03,
case When FechaMon = 4 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber04,
case When FechaMon = 5 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber05,
case When FechaMon = 6 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber06,
case When FechaMon = 7 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber07,
case When FechaMon = 8 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber08,
case When FechaMon = 9 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber09,
case When FechaMon = 10 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber10,
case When FechaMon = 11 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber11,
case When FechaMon = 12 then d.Importe end as SaldoHaber12

From Cuentas as c inner join #FechaDiarioHaber as d on c.Código = d.Cuenta
Where d.Fecha >= @fechaDesde and d.Fecha <= @fechaHasta 

)table1
group by Cuenta
order by Cuenta
```

Comment: Table Cuentas has not field 'Fecha'; this field belongs to table Diario

Comment: The query takes more than 2 minutes and i just stopping it.

Comment: @MGG_Soft - Have edited the code again. Can you please let me know how much time it is taking this time?

Comment: @MGG_Soft - Can you please let me know how much time the query takes **now**? I would be obliged. Thanks!

Comment: It takes four seconds.